# References for combining LFSRs with different lengths and taps?

Tags: algorithm-design, reference-request, stream-cipher, xor, lfsr

I started learning streams ciphers with the use of LFSRs. Therefore, I tried to simulate what I am learning in a `C` sourcecode, which combines three registers and XOR with function $X$ to get stream keys – but I couldn't find examples or resources which illustrate the same thing to help me do so.

Are there any guidelines which can show me how to achieve the above, or any references codes which explain or maybe even simulate that scenario?

Comment: your statement is unclear. do you take the 3 outputs and pass them through a boolean function ($X$?) or do you xor them with X. What is X?